# fread from data.table package can't read small numbers

Tags: r, csv, memory-management, data.table

I am using `fread()` from `data.table` to efficiently read large rectangular CSV files into `R` which are all `double` (and only `double`) values -- no missing elements.

However if I have very very small numbers in scientific notation, it'll get converted to character which ruins the whole read. Here is the error message (as an example, there are multiple for each small number):

> 16: In fread("SomeCSVFile") :
>   Bumped column 560 to type character on data row 16799, field contains '-2.1412168512924677E-308'. Coercing previously read values in this column from integer or numeric back to character which may not be lossless; e.g., if '00' and '000' occurred before they will now be just '0', and there may be inconsistencies with treatment of ',,' and ',NA,' too (if they occurred in this column before the bump). If this matters please rerun and set 'colClasses' to 'character' for this column. Please note that column type detection uses the first 5 rows, the middle 5 rows and the last 5 rows, so hopefully this message should be very rare. If reporting to datatable-help, please rerun and include the output from verbose=TRUE.

I want the function to set them to zero or truncate them at the minimum possible value (either is fine).

Comment: This question can be hugely improved by providing some sample data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: What is the real problem?  Do you have any real use for those small values?  Who allowed the Excel sheet to generate them in the first place?  If you're going to set them to zero anyway, just read them in and then `matrix[is.character(matrix)]<-numeric(0)`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I don't use Excel but thanks for the solution.

Comment: Oops my bad for assuming all `csv` spawned from the vile pit of Excel.

Comment: when I try putting numbers with very small exponent, they get read as 0 - you need to add a reproducible example + operating system/package details for you setup - as is this is not a good question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reproduce this, I put this content in a text file:

```
x
1
1
1
1
1
1e-309
```

Then I called `fread("that file.txt")`.

---

The size of the smallest positive number that R can store is

```
format(.Machine$double.xmin, digits = 22)
## [1] "2.2250738585072013828e-308"
```

Your data file includes the value `-2.1412168512924677E-308`, which is smaller than this limit.  To prevent R treating the value as zero, the `data.table` package has converted the column to be strings.  This stops the data precision being lost.

If you need to work with values of this size, then use the `Rmpfr` package to store the numbers with more precision.  Import them as characters (using `colClasses`; see that data table warning text).  Then use

```
library(Rmpfr)
mpfr("-2.1412168512924677E-308")
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  70   bits 
## [1] -2.1412168512924676999992e-308
```

---

As Ben Bolker siad in the comments.  If you don't care about the tiny numbers, and just want to treat them as zero, then import the column as characters, then use `as.numeric`.

```
the_data <- fread("the file.txt", colClasses = "character")
the_data$DodgyColumn <- as.numeric(the_data$DodgyColumn)
```

Comment: But this means I can't even use the `fread` anymore if my matrix is not uniformly numbers. How do I fix this from a practical point of view, knowing that the difference between `-2.14...E-308` and `-2.225..E-308` is nothing to my use case (i.e. get it to round down to zero or something sensible).

Comment: You can use `fread`; you just need to specify the `colClasses` arguement.  Re-read that warning text.

Comment: Have you actually reproduced OP's issue (and if so, can you please add a reproducible example to your answer)? What they describe doesn't happen for me - small numbers get read as 0.

Comment: @eddi Answer updated as requested.  Make the first 5 numbers sensible, so the column is treated as numeric, then provide a very small number.

Comment: @RichieCotton thanks - I cannot reproduce this on either Windows or Linux, R 3.0.1, dt 1.8.11 - that column is being read as numeric just fine

Comment: you need to go a little smaller to get reliable answers -- I think things are *very* sensitive to numerical details around the boundary.  Try `1e-340`.

Comment: @BenBolker when I try `1e-340` the column *still* gets read as numeric, with `1e-340` being read as `0` (on both Windows and Linux), so I'm still unable to reproduce the issue

Comment: maybe worth pointing out that if you read in as character and then coerce with `as.numeric()` the OP will get the behaviour they want (underflow of very small numbers).

Comment: I'm using dt 1.8.10, maybe that's the difference?

Comment: I'm also using data.table `1.8.10`.

Comment: From 1.8.11 news: "`fread("1.46761e-313\n")` detected the ERANGE error, so read as character. It now reads as numeric but with a detailed warning. Thanks to Heather Turner for the detailed report, [#4879](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=975&aid=4879&group_id=240)."